# Set date formart in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'd  like to display the `abbreviated` name of the month in the `gridview` for example `11/Aug/2015`

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridsrev" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered  text-nowrap" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" HeaderText="Select" SelectText="Preview" ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S.R.NO" HeaderText="S.R.NO" SortExpression="S.R.NO"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Agrement ID" HeaderText="Agrement ID" SortExpression="Agrement ID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CUST_ID" HeaderText="CUST ID" SortExpression="CUST_ID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service Type" HeaderText="Service Type" SortExpression="Service Type"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service Date" HeaderText="Service Date" SortExpression="Service Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Next Service" HeaderText="Next Service" SortExpression="Next Service" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
```

Comment: And? What happens with the code you've already got?

Comment: date show in this format  8/11/2015

Comment: Date formatting works only with `DateTime` type. Make sure `Service Date` and `Next Service` are `DateTime` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add htmlEncode and set it to true. Try this :

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Service Date" HeaderText="Service Date" SortExpression="Service Date"  HtmlEncodeFormatString="true" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Next Service" HeaderText="Next Service" SortExpression="Next Service"  HtmlEncodeFormatString="true" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrond you need to set **htmlEncode=false** for your **BoundField** with **DataFormatString**
It will disable the encoding of html and use your DataFormatString

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried using your `DataFormatString` in my ASP.Net GridView, and it changed the date format to exactly what you were looking for:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"  HeaderStyle-Width="100px" />
```

This produced a column of dates in this format:

```
11.Jan.2013
```

(My language settings have full-stop as the date separator character.)

Perhaps this is an issue with your data ?